# ADO.NET reports an entity association error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I got two tables named Personnel and Department.

```
**Personnel Table ;**
PERSONNELID int , PK not null
NAME varchar
SURNAME varchar
DepartmentID integer 

Department Table ;
DepartmentID  int , PK not null
DEPARTMENTNAME varchar

(ONE TO MANY Relation)
```

I want to create an association between these tables, but I can't do it with EDMX Model Designer. I am getting errors:

> Association END KEY property PERSONNELID is not mapped.
> Association END KEY property NAME is not mapped.

I am new at this framework.  Is there any easy way of do this job in the Entity Framework?

I am using Firebird 2.1 DB and Firebird.Client.Data 2.5.0.0 for provider.

Comment: Probably not a one-to-one relationship unless each department has only one person, probably n-to-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a one-to-one relationship to work each table must have the same primary (unique) key.

In your case you probably have a one to many relationship:

One department can have many persons.

Comment: ok one to one , one to many , its not important cuz i cant do association thing in Entity Framework .. is there any tutorial about this ?

Comment: These relations _are_ important because they're captured by the entity framework from the schema.

Comment: Are these relationships spesified in your database? Are the primary keys and foreign keys spesified? If all of these are in place EF should generate the model for you.

Comment: Have you installed the Firebird extensions for Visual Studio?